# HIve shell exception java type java.lang.Integer cant be mapped for this datastore

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive

I have hadoop and hbase installed. When i run show tables comand in hive shell the following error raised.

```
Hive version 0.10.0

Hbase version 0.90.6

Hadoop version 1.1.2

hive> show tables;

FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.MetaException javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: JDBC type integer declared for field 
"org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable.createTime" of java type java.lang.Integer cant be mapped for this datastore.

NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: JDBC type integer declared for field "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MTable.createTime" of java type java.lang.Integer cant be mapped for this datastore.)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem comes from. Error is related to language settings of the linux box. Before launching hive `export LANG=C` is needful.